# Batch-driven or event-driven ETL

Tags: data-engineering, etl

I am trying to come up with a data pipeline architecture. The data I deal with is event logging for labs requested, failed, succeeded etc with timestamps and some customer info for several different customers. Eventually I want that data being dumped into a dashboard, for both external and internal use. What's the best way to approach it: event-driven or batch driven ETL? We don't care much for real-time processing, and the data is rather small.

Answer (score 1):

If real-time [ETL](https://databasecamp.de/en/data/etl-en) processing is not important, then use batch-driven processing. It is easier for you to monitor since you know the pipeline schedule and you save hardware by scheduling it to more quiet times.